# using gzipped js files in windows 8 OS

Tags: leaflet, html

Previously, we were using a private ISP to run our web site. They were using LINUX. We could use js.gz files to serve interactive maps.
Now, we have our own server with Windows 8 OS.
How we can serve js.gz files in this system to serve interactive maps?
Are there any other compressing system to serve maps with Windows 8 OS?

Comment: How does your OS matter? Your webserver should deal with it. I know that Apache and IIS & nginx can gzip on the fly.